# InfoPath Repeating Table-Add Filtered Data from Secondary List

Tags: list, infopath, office-365

I have the following scenario that I am trying to get find a solution for.

I have two lists within my SharePoint site called Supplier and Factory. The relationship between the supplier and factory list is one to many, that is for each unique supplier there can be multiple factories that are related to it.

So in the factory list there is a lookup column to the supplier list, a parent-child type relationship between them.

Within InfoPath I am trying to create a form for the Supplier list that will show all of the "child" factories related to that supplier in a repeating table. I have managed to get the repeating table into the supplier form, however the problem I have is that at the moment it includes all of the factories in the list, not just those related to the specific supplier I am looking at.

Is there a way to auto-filter the repeating table so that when the supplier form is opened up, it only displays those factories that have identified themselves as factories of that specific supplier?

I am using SharePoint 365 and InfoPath 2013.

Thanks

**Edit**

I have added an image below to help better illustrate my scenario.

The image is the view of an item in the supplier list, specifically supplier S2 with ID 2. The table in latter half of the image is the repeating table which is pulling in from the factory list. As you can see it is pulling in everything that exists in that list at the moment, I want it to only pull in those factories which have a matching Supplier ID of the supplier item that is open. So in this case it would be the bottom two factories F5 and F6 (they are the only factories with a matching supplier ID of 2).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking to do cascading drop downs? If so, here's a [link to a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SH7xUEcQwwg/) that seems very helpful.

Comment: That is along the lines of what I am after, but not quite. I need to apply it to repeating tables, not just fields.